# how do i generate url strings in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have watched some tutorials and read a book on basics of beautifulsoup, wrote this scraper, but cannot get it to cycle through urls a-z or go through pages. For this project i am scraping a website AND i want to be able to have it scrape A-Z and not just page A results.

**Code below was working until i tried to get it to generate the last letter string --**

**Here BELOW is my NOT working code - my attempt at building the url string. Ideally i would love to pull from a file or predefined list as well but baby steps.**

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from string import ascii_lowercase

def make_soup(url):
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
return soupdata


playerdatasaved=""
for letter in ascii_lowercase:
soup = make_soup("http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/" + letter +      "/")
  for record in soup.find_all("tr"):
    playerdata=""
    for data in record.findAll("td"):
        playerdata=playerdata+","+data.text
    if len(playerdata)!=0:
        playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]

header="Player,From,To,Pos,Ht,Wt,Birth Date,College"
file = open(os.path.expanduser("Basketball.csv"),"wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))

print(letter)
print(playerdatasaved)
```

**MY ERRORS ARE BELOW
---------------------**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python36/web_scraper_tutorial/multiple_url_2.py", line 15, in <module>
 soup = make_soup("http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/" + letter + "/")
 File "C:/Python36/web_scraper_tutorial/multiple_url_2.py", line 8, in    make_soup
   thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 564, in error
   result = self._call_chain(*args)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
 result = func(*args)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
 return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
 response = meth(req, response)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
 return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
 result = func(*args)
 File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Anyone give me some assistance or advice?

below is the working version for just one page - i need it to crawl multiple.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
return soupdata

playerdatasaved=""
soup = make_soup("http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/")
for record in soup.find_all("tr"):
playerdata = ""
for data in record.findAll("td"):
    playerdata=playerdata+","+data.text
playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]

header="Player,From,To,Pos,Ht,Wt,Birth Date,College"+"\n"
file = open(os.path.expanduser("Basketball.csv"),"wb")
file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))
file.write(bytes(playerdatasaved, encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))


print(playerdatasaved)
```

Comment: the error says the response with that url wasn't found, so you are generating a url that isn't available in the respective server.

Comment: I figured as much but can you tell me why? any url with a-z should be valid - what is wrong with how i have this setup? I posted the first version crawling a single url - need multiple.

Comment: I cannot tell you why a server decides to work on a way their programmers intended. Also in your example it looks like the "X" is unavailable (404)

Comment: Based on your responses I think you dont understand my goal here. The title and my question was "how do i generate url strings in beautifulsoup."  I have the first part with a single URL working and also my attempt posted that seems to be very close to working but clearly something is wrong with how i am generating the last part of the url.

Answer (score 0):

That particular site does not have an 'x'.  Thus you will get a 404.  Wrap it in a try except so it will skip pages that are 404 and it should work.

```
playerdatasaved=""
for letter in ascii_lowercase:
    try:
        soup = make_soup("http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/" + letter +      "/")
        for record in soup.find_all("tr"):
        playerdata=""
        for data in record.findAll("td"):
            playerdata=playerdata+","+data.text
        if len(playerdata)!=0:
            playerdatasaved = playerdatasaved + "\n" + playerdata[1:]
    except:
        pass
```